# Search a title word through query_posts (not the exact match)

Tags: filters, query-posts, forms

We're working on a database with personal data from different sportsmen such as name, height, weight, etc.

We've managed to build a detailed filter through `query_posts`.

Every filter field is working as expected except for the text input field that we use to filter the sportsman by name. The problem is that when we are looking for the name of a single sportsman, the form just allows us to find the sportsmen by its exact name.

For example: If we are looking for a sportsman called John Doe, we would need to write the exact name of the post title ('John Doe'). Instead, we would like to be able to have results just typing 'John' or 'Doe'.

Our `query_posts` filter looks like this:

```
query_posts( array(
    'name' => $sportsman_name,
    'post_type' => 'db',
    'posts_per_page' => 100,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'category_name' => $sport,
    'meta_query' => array(
        $height,
        $weight,
        $tshirt_size,
        $foot_size,

    )
) );
```

That's how the form field looks like:

`<input name="sportsman" type="text">`

And that's how we create the string to filter the results in the `query_posts`:

```
$sportsman = $_GET["sportsman"];

    if($sportsman == ''){
        $sportsman_name = null;
    }else{
        $sportsman_name = $sportsman;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use search parameter 's' instead of 'name'

```
query_posts( array(
's' => $sportsman_name,
'post_type' => 'db',
'posts_per_page' => 100,
'paged' => $paged,
'category_name' => $sport,
'meta_query' => array(
    $height,
    $weight,
    $tshirt_size,
    $foot_size,
)));
```

Answer (score 0):

First, use `WP_query` instead of `query_posts`.

```
$my_query = new WP_query( args... );
if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    $my_query->the_post();
    $sportsman = ...
}
```

Second, to not filter by exact values you might use regular expressions (e.g., set the name within the array to `"/^.*{$sportsman_name}.*$/"`). Id **did not test** that.